# Is the mentioned sentence properly constructed?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> The difference between A and B amounts to **that** A is beneficial
>   while B is not.

I don't know if "that" is properly used in this sentence. I couldn't come up with a better sentence which is as concise as this. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: "amounts to" must be changed to **is**.  **that** is used correctly.

Comment: Or ''...amounts to **the fact that** A is beneficial..."

Comment: perhaps: boils down to  is better than amounts to here......

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I want to keep "amount to".

Comment: **amounts to the fact that** is hardly "concise".

Comment: @stangdon I don't like to use "the fact that" while I like to use "amount to".

Comment: **amounts to** +  {nominal}

Comment: This question would be better asked on verbosity.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Is the suggestion in one answer acceptable: The difference between A and B amounts to A being beneficial while B is not.>> I am asking because of using "is" after when we used "being" before seems ungrammatical in this sentence.

Comment: @user157323. *The difference between you and me is that I'm a native speaker of English and you're not.* Or more concisely, *I'm a native speaker of English and you're not.*   If you insist on **amounts to**, then you must do as stangdon suggested, but **amounts to the fact that** is hardly concise.

Comment: @user157323 - OK, but *why* do you want to use "amount to"?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need *amounts to* in there:

> The difference between A and B **amounts to** A being beneficial while B is not.

No *that*.
The usage of *that* in "amounts to that" is different.

> You might not think you were hurting her, but everything you did **amounts to that**.